# Linear Regression P-Value Interpretation

Tags: regression, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, p-value, linear

I'm struggling to interpret the p_value from a linear regression I ran. The model is clearly linear, i.e. E[Y|X] is linear. Why would it be the case that I have a large p-value given this result?

My understanding of a p-value is that a low p-value will cause you to reject the null hypothesis, i.e. that there is no linear relationship. And a high p-value will cause you to accept the null hypothesis, i.e. you conclude that there is a linear relationship.

Given the results below, how could it be possible to generate this regression fit and produce a high p-value?

P Value = 0.347012
R Squared = 0.663615

[image]

[image]

Comment: how did you calculate the p-value?

Comment: Some further details about the model/data might help. For example: (1) does the figure show all of the data or are there points outside the range shown? (2) is there only one independent variable or are there others not shown on the figure (e.g. is this a simple regression or a multiple regression)? (3) How was the model specified (equation, software used, etc).?

Comment: @rep_ho i used this python statistics module: 

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.pvalues.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.pvalues

Comment: @dlid
the figure shows all the data that went into the regression. The X-axis is the dependent variable and the Y-axis is the independent variable, it is a single variable regression

the software used was using the python package statsmodel.api as mentioned above

Comment: well, it is definitely wrong, this is not a p-value corresponding to r2 0.66 for your number of points. That should be extremely significant. As far as I remember statsmodels don't include an intercept in the model by default, did you include it?

Comment: @rep_ho bless you, your comment made me look at my code again, these are p-values for the intercept. I am an idiot and was indexing the statsmodel p_value output at 0 instead of 1